# Is there a book, website ...etc that can explain mathematical ideas without details, just the philosophy behind such ideas?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Something like what an expert might extract from a theorem, or a mathematical concept that would help you better grasp and understand the idea and/or concept?

Comment: The "reference-request" tag seemed like a good idea, but feel free to remove it if you disagree.

Comment: Ian Stewart, [Visions of infinity: The great mathematical problems](https://books.google.it/books?id=I-RSVN6TjXsC&printsec=frontcover) (2013).

Comment: Richard Courant & Herbert Robbins, [What Is Mathematics?: An Elementary Approach to Ideas and Methods](https://books.google.it/books?id=UfdossHPlkgC&printsec=frontcover) (1941).

Comment: I think Terence Tao's blog is good for this (although I usually don't have the background to understand what's being written about). He does give details but also gives a big picture view.

Comment: [Some of these posts might work](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question)

Comment: Could you give  a concrete example of you what have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Pop mathematics is best represented by E.T.Bell's

> [Men of Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_of_Mathematics).

It is full of inaccuracies, both mathematical and historical, but is a cheerful read if you want to feel that you have learned something *about* mathematics without learning *mathematics*.

Answer (score 0):

Many mathematical entries in Wikipedia start with an informal description which should fill your requirement.
Just to give you a concrete example, let me quote the wikipedia entry for [Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology):

> In mathematics, topology (from the Greek τόπος, place, and λόγος,
>   study) is concerned with the properties of space that are preserved
>   under continuous deformations, such as stretching, crumpling and
>   bending, but not tearing or gluing. This can be studied by considering
>   a collection of subsets, called open sets, that satisfy certain
>   properties, turning the given set into what is known as a topological
>   space.